# source activate & conda create doesn't work with a bash shell

Tags: conda, git-bash

I am dealing with a calculation of drought climate indices, for which I have to install a bash shell under my windows 10 system. I already did this and I have two versions of bash shell with me now: Cygwin and Babun.

But when I tried to create a new python environment within the bash shell, I got the following error:

```
harve@DESKTOP-P9EREI9 ~
$ conda
-bash: conda: command not found

harve@DESKTOP-P9EREI9 ~
$ source C:/Users/harve/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

harve@DESKTOP-P9EREI9 ~
$ conda create -n py_indices
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pk
gs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.


If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

So it seems I got some HTTP errors.. I already closed all my firewalls defenders, I tried to restart, I tried to close and rerun... None of them worked.

Does anyone have an idea of how to forward?

Many thanks!

Hao

Comment: Do `conda` commands work from the anaconda command prompt?

Comment: Hi, yes everything works well in anaconda command prompt, but in my case I have to work in a bash shell so...

Comment: How did you install Conda?